# android studio start failed - Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, macos

> > Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of
>   com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull
>   parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.
>   must not be null
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.(Platform.java)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
>       ... 16 more

i tried to reinstall but nothing worked.
my android studio not starting.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you trying to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio can't start after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation)

Comment: Just turn off the Internet connection. Worked for me [Found it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem and found this post:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183063&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

It looks like a older version of Android Studio is the culprit. Try downloading from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: @braden-edmunds ya that's worked....but now i am getting "checksum error" after download api level 22

Comment: @AnirudhSharma, I don't think this is a link-only answer. His statement summarized the problem found at the first link pretty well "It looks like a older version of Android Studio is the culprit." Then the second link points to the solution, the official primary site to download the latest Android tools for Android developers, I don't think he could have done better than that. This is not like the other cases, where people link to a potentially defunct blog where there is a crucial snippet of code that future visitors won't be able to get at because it wasn't pasted into the original answer.

Comment: I was having the same issue in opening the Android Studio from the task bar Shortcut. I just reinstall Android Studio, all goes well, might be helpful for someone.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to Launch without Internet Connection

Answer (score 4):

Open the folder "bin" under the directory where you installed your Android Studio. Find the file "idea.properties" and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools. Add "disable.android.first.run=true" as the final line and save the file. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

Found a temporary solution from Issue #170850

Add the following code to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I just downloaded newer version and installed it. Problem got solved. So it seems this problem occurs because of older version of Android studio.