# Android Studio can't start after installation

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android Studio, it doesn't start, but it displays the following error when fetching Android SDK component information:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062923/android-studio-start-failed-java-lang-illegalargumentexception

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just turn off the Internet connection.

Comment: Why would this help the OP?

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Kill the internet, open the app it will launch then connect back internet and perform update to 1.4, mostly likely if you are already on 1.3 or 1.4 you wont be facing this issue.

Comment: thanks a lot  :) ,i work well when i turn the internet off

Comment: This didn't work for me. See Xun Chenglong's answer below.

Comment: I tried installing Studio 3 times total before looking up. I am feeling very angry now. Thanks man, it worked.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, Why this is says error. Solution is When Connected Internet Android Studio Check it is Updated Version so server says that itz not so Android Studio Cannot handle and get it Error. When We are Offline Android Studio do not Connect Server so Software Working Perfectly. Even Second Opening software not check this because all of folders for supporting will created on first Launch.

Comment: this worked for me. BUT WHY? Also, not needed on a second machine with an identical install.

Answer (score 114):

It occurred to me today. I think the reason is that mistakes occurred when fetching Android SDK component information. Here is my way to avoid this problem:

1. Open the folder `bin` under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
2. Find the file `idea.properties` and open it with [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit), or other edit tools.
3. Add `disable.android.first.run=true` as the final line and save the file.
4. Restart Android Studio.

Then it won't fetch any information and will be opened directly. I hope that will help you.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Worked in Windows 10

Comment: Worked in Mac 10.9.5 Thx!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu `14.04LTS`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Simply starting Android Studio when the Internet connection is off worked for me.

It will give a warning message that it cannot initiate the first run. Just ignore that warning, and you are done.

Comment: If I ignore that message, it then crashes for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the two folders C:\Users\USER_NAME.android and C:\Users\USER_NAME.AndroidStudio. And delete all files in C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp
2. Remove and re-install Android Studio, and I used the SDK that I downloaded before and saved it as backup. Then I opened Android Studio when the Internet connection was off.

The best way is, make sure you do the 1st step up here then
turn off the internet then restart you computer.

Answer (score 1):

Please press okay and restart Android Studio. It will start normally.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upgrade Android Studio to the stable 1.3.1 version. From the log, it seems there is a problem with an argument which seems to be null.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug found in earlier versions of Android Studio and is reported by many users.

See *[Issue 183063:    Start Failed - parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183063&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)*.

The best solution for now would be downloading the latest version of Android Studio which is **version 1.3**.