# Android sdk studio fails to initialize

Tags: android, sdk

how to solve java runtime error on initializing Android SDK Studio?been trying to fix this for days now. The installation seems succesful, but when I try ti run the android sdk studio, java errors occurs. Anyone? pls help. Btw I'm running on windows 7-64bit system. Below is the error code.

> Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more

Comment: Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Comment: @invariant  thanks for the quick response, Can't go on the exact error since Im not using my PC not. As I could recall java run time error. Though I make sure I already have JDK installed on my PC

Comment: @adriaan sorry I cant broadly explain the details of the error as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem after an update.
I uninstalled all Java versions on my system (I had multiple: 1.7 and 1.8) and Android Studio from my system; then, made a fresh installation of the latest JDK, and the latest Android Studio and everything was solved.

Hope it can help

EDIT: this question has duplicates, you may find the correct solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133505/2003114); the issue is related to fetching component informations from the net.

Comment: will try it tommorrow, btw may I know your configurations on your java set up?and are u using windows 7 64-bit? I already reformat my computer, everything is freshly setup and installed JDK 7 instead, but still not working

Comment: @starTreyk yes, i'm running win7 64bit. You should provide more infos about your error.. and firstly, which version of Java and Android studio are you running now? Please provide a screenshot of your error if you can't copy/paste or trace it in any other way

Comment: I'll post here the exact error tom. For the version of JDK I'm using jdk1.7.0_79  for the android I'm using the latest version. You dont have any configuration on system variables before you installed the android studio??

Comment: @starTreyk I don't remember the setup before reinstalling JRE/Android Studio; but, currently, in my **PATH** sysvar I have _C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71_ and I also have a **JAVA_HOME** set to _C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80_

Comment: Is that all the values of your var PATH on sysvar? How about on your user var??Thanks for your reply

Comment: now that you exposed your exception, IMMO your question becomes a duplicate. try this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32133505/2003114)

Comment: Thanks @stefano your solution really worked as a charm!:)

Comment: great, remember to describe your issues as best as you can.. you could have find a solution yesterday ;)