# Start failed for Android studio in win 8

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed JDK7 & AS on my new machine (win 8)
When I try to start Android studio it show me this error [Start Failed -Internal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuKlw.jpg)

I have **Path** set to the bin folder in jdk,

**JAVA_HOME** set to the jdk folder.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation) helps?

Comment: @AuroMetal yes it worked ! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @user64184 glad it did. Don't forget to upvote the answer on that thread that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

After download and install Java SE Development Kit 7 - "jdk-7u21-windows-x64.exe" from Oracle site then adds JAVA_HOME **(value = c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21)** to environment variables. It works fine with me on Windows 8.