# Cant launch Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I Installed the latest Android Studio on my Windows 8.1 64bit PC and also the Java version requiered. When i start Android studio i get the error messeage:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more
```

I tried to reinstall but got the same messeage again. Does any know what the error log means?

Comment: try downloading android studio and the sdk separately, download android studio, and download the standalone sdk and use it instead of the bundled one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio can't start after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation)

Answer (score 0):

while you didn't config the android enviroment, it will product a error.
by add "disable.android.first.run=true" in the idea.properties file in the end as the article said.
[Android Studio can't start after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation)