# Android Studio 2.2.1.0 under Windows 7 32bit professional edition can't start after installation?

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 2.2.1.0 in my Windows 7 32bit professional edition, and I have upgraded JAVA to V1.8.8_111, 
and I have set the environment var JAVA_HOME as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111`  (The path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111` doesn't work!), but I get the following error when I try to open Android Studio.

I try to fix the problem using all the ways listed at [Android Studio can't start after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation)
but I can't start  Android Studio 2.2.1.0 yet!

**My Java path:**

[image]

**The error information:**

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.access$300(ProjectManagerImpl.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$3.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:311)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.getDefaultProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:282)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.access$801(ApplicationImpl.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$12.run(ApplicationImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/Value
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.<init>(EventDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.create(EventDispatcher.java:42)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerStateManager.java:29)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl$MyDebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:606)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl$MyDebuggerStateManager.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:606)
    at com.intellij.debugger.impl.DebuggerManagerImpl.<init>(DebuggerManagerImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.Value
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Any ideas for me ?

Comment: Could you help me ?