# Android studio not starting after plugin update in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, android-studio

Following exception is displayed after starting android studio:

```
Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:204)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'null'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:432)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:412)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

Studio was working fine until plugin update. After downloading the patch and restarting studio,the pop up displayed "can not update plugin due to following dependencies".

I have tried restarting the computer, deleting plugins/extensions as suggested in few answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to turn off internet connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation

Comment: Issue still persist...

Comment: Deleted all settings and reinstalled android studio. That resolved the issue.

Comment: That's the last thing one must do. :)

Comment: No budget for the most basic Q&A?? How can they launch Android studio updates without even checking this?? Android is becoming a disgrace.