# Android Studio stopped responding and now it won't start. Gives a lot of errors starting with java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android-studio

I have the same problem as in [android studio start failed - Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062923/android-studio-start-failed-java-lang-illegalargumentexception) question but I haven't found any answer over there.I was using android studio and it just stopped responding so I restarted my laptop and now it won't start showing this error.

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
... 16 more
```

How to set it back. I dont want to lose my projects.

Comment: see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090832/android-studio-cant-start-after-installation

Comment: I just had to update my java version. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my java version and this worked for me.